# MOV wear sensing

Tags: sensing, mov

How would one go about to implement accurate sensing of metal oxide varistor wear level?

Even cheapo surge protects come with a LED to indicate protection status, but I presume this is not based on actual sensing, but most likely a "time fuse" that simply prompts the use to replace the device, regardless of the amount of wear.

I've read that MOVs mitigate power surges by absorbing some of the energy and redirecting another portion to ground. And that they burn out when overloaded. In other words, the amount of thermal energy they generate is proportional to the amount of wear.

So one possibility might be to try and measure how much heat is displaced into the ambience, but it sounds kinda complex and course, and presumably most of the time the wear is rather subtle.

Maybe something else? I am interested in accuracy of measurement, not in economic viability, obviously MOVs are fairly cheap and typically do not merit sensing sensing circuitry that will be much more expensive.

Comment: AFAIK a common failure mode for MOVs is to fail to a short circuit after they get 'worn out' by absorbing many surges. As such they're always connected inline with a fuse (probably a high-rating slow-blow type) so that when they do finally die they're disconnected from the circuit - and it's this state that the el-cheapo LED indicator is showing you.

Comment: I want to measure the actual wear, not whether or not it has reached a level of catastrophic failure.

Comment: Maybe an inline current sensor which you sample frequently (fast enough to catch surges) and integrate over time...

Comment: It's not trivial.  If you can get a hold of the following IEEE paper it explains one approach: "Research on leakage current characteristic of metal oxide varistor" by Xuni Rao et. al.

Comment: @brhans - won't that measure how much goes through the MOV rather than how much it absorbs? It will have to measure before and after and find the difference.

Comment: The MOV is connected in parallel with the power lines it is protecting. The only time there's current flowing through it is when it's absorbing something. Most of the time there's nothing (other than leakage) flowing through the MOV.

Comment: @brhans I don't think that's true, there is current that will open up the MOV, which is the energy it absorbs, and there is also current that will flow through it into the ground.

Comment: That wasn't an opinion. MOVs *are* connected in parallel to whatever they' protecting. Look at some MOV tutorials, like [here](http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/select-right-varistors-overvoltage-circuit-protection) and [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/varistor.html). The MOV does nothing (aside from leakage) until the *voltage* across it's terminals rises to a specified level - after that it allows *current* to flow through itself. The energy it absorbs during a surge is a result of the current flowing through it once its voltage rating has been reached.